# Retrieving text between two terms

Tags: bash, sed

I have looked at several of the answers related to this question, however, I still can not get exactly what I need to work.

Essentially, I am writing a paper that uses bibliographic codes in a mark-up container. This may occur in several ways, e.g.:

```
\citet{bibcode}
\citep{bibcode}
\citet{bibcode1,bibcode2}
\citep[randomtext]{bibcode}
```

etc.

I am trying to compile a list of purely these bibcodes. Where there are multiple bibcodes in a single container, they are separated by a comma.

Currently, I am using:

```
sed -n 's:.*\cite.*{\(.*\)}.*:\1:p' sample.tex
```

It works for some instances, though, not with all. It appears to still get distracted by other uses of the curly brackets, and picks up a lot of unnecessary text.

Any help regarding this matter would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can give few more sample (where it is not working...) Show input samples and expected output.If there are other curly brackets, your command will not do what u want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no more than one citation on each line, you could adjust your regex to be something like this:

```
s:.*\\cite[^{]*{\([^}]*\)}.*:\1:p
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Balthamos. Your updated regex has omitted those instances where extra text was added. However, it is not picking up all the instances of the \cite{} command, even ones that only have one bibcode located between the braces. Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: Could you give an example of the line that is failing? I've tested it with `\cite{foobar}` and it appeared to work. As I said before, if you have more than one `\cite` per line, it will only pick up the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the sample input you gave:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[{},]" }
/\\cite/ {
    for (i=2;i<NF;i++) {
        if (!seen[$i]++) {
            print $i
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
bibcode
bibcode1
bibcode2
```

If your real input is more complicated/difficult to parse than that then update your question to show some input that more accurately demonstrates your problem and the associated output you are looking for.